# AngularJS - Select value returns "? number:x ?" from scope variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Trying to get the initial value for a select element and instead of populating the value, it adds a weird string as seen in this image:

[image]

Here is the JavaScript code:

```
 function appCtrl($scope){
        $scope.teams = [
            {teamId: 10, teamName: 'Foo'},
            {teamId: 20, teamName: 'Bar'},
            {teamId: 30, teamName: 'Steve'},
            {teamId: 40, teamName: 'Jobs'},
            {teamId: 50, teamName: 'Macs'}
        ];

        $scope.filters = {
            teamIdSelected: 20
        };
  }
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="appCtrl"> 
    <select class="small" ng-model="filters.teamIdSelected">
        <option ng-repeat="team in teams" value="{{team.teamId}}">{{team.teamName}}</option>
    </select>
```

Here is a jsbin to demonstrate: http://jsbin.com/EKOpAFI/1/edit

I also tried using the incredibly poorly documented select element [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:select) but I can't get it to work that way either where my teamId is the value and the teamName is the label. It always wants to put the index of the array as the value.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`select` directive is really a bit hard to grok. Here's how it works in conjunction with `ng-options` directive (which is amazingly powerful!)

```
<select 
  ng-model="filters.teamIdSelected"
  ng-options="value.teamId as value.teamName for (key, value) in teams"
  ></select>
```

Don't get confused with the values generated in the DOM when inspecting the selects options with dev tools. The `value` attribute always gets its index. Corresponding key values pairs still get evaluated against scope, so all you need is to update ´ng-model`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 5):

I recommend using ng-options on the select element instead, like so:

```
    <select class="small" ng-model="filters.teamIdSelected" ng-options="team.teamId as team.teamName for team in teams"></select>
```

Additionally, if you want to include a "Select Team" option:

```
<select class="small" ng-model="filters.teamIdSelected" ng-options="team.teamId as team.teamName for team in teams">
  <option value="">Select Team</options>      
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want:

```
<select class="small" ng-model="filters.teamIdSelected"
    ng-options="t.teamId as t.teamName for t in teams">
</select>
```

Dont use `ng-repeat` with `<option>`s.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question has been answered several years ago, but if anyone encounters the same issue and the solutions don't work, try track by $index.

```
<select class="small" ng-model="filters.teamIdSelected"
    ng-options="t.teamId as t.teamName for t in teams track by $index">
</select>
```